# Empty Directory Selection in Electron

Tags: html, electron

I am using

`<input type="file" webkitdirectory />`

for directory selection in electron ( A sample App. No React/Angular inside. Simple index.html ).

Using onChange I am able to get the directory which is selected.

But, the onChange function does not get called when an empty directory is selected. I need this functionality.

scenario being the user selects a folder to download an report or something.

I found some alternates ; but webkitdirectory seems the easiest. Wonder why it does not work.

Update:
Okay so I checked the files list in the event and I am not getting folder path. But if files at present then it shows files path; But still not getting selected folder path

Regards,

Comment: Have the same issue, need to allow users to select a data folder to store files, want them to select an empty folder, but that doesn't trigger the change event. Did you figure out a solution?